# Compact, not totally bounded but complete

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, complete-spaces

Is there any metric space which is compact, not totally bounded but complete? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. If $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space, then, for $\epsilon>0$, the open covering of $X$ by all $\epsilon$-balls
$$\bigcup_{x\in X} B(x,\epsilon)$$
must have a finite subcoveringe which means that $X$ is totally bounded.